# D3.js: draw simple, updatable line graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to draw a simple line graph in D3, but having a few problems.

I want the graph to be dynamic - so when the data updates, I'd like the graph to transition to the new values. So I need to use D3 transitions somewhere in my code, and I can't find a good example of doing that with a line graph.

Here are the relevant parts of my code. At the moment, this isn't drawing anything at all.

```
var data = [
 {
  "air_produced": 0.660985, 
  "air_used": 0.342706, 
  "datestr": "2012-12-01 00:00:00", 
  "energy_used": 0.106402
 } ... ];
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate.parse(d.datestr);
});

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(d.energy_used); });

// How to draw the line?
var linegraph = d3.select("path.line").datum(data);
line.transition().duration(1000).attr("d", line);
linegraph.enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);
```

JSFiddle here with the full graph: http://jsfiddle.net/zNX8p/

Comment: This seems to have a working example: http://bl.ocks.org/benjchristensen/2579599

Comment: That doesn't show how to update the line when there's new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it (I think):

```
var linegraph = svg.selectAll("path.line").data([data], function(d) { return d.date; });

linegraph.transition().duration(1000).attr('d', line);

linegraph.enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);
```

`datum` does not return an `enter` selection, so you need to pass the data via `data` instead.

Comment: Did this end up working? I am stuck in the same step.

Answer (score 1):

d3 has a general update pattern that you should use for this case.

The convention is to have two functions, one to setup the visualization, and another to take data and update the visualization.

The update function takes in the new data, binds it, updates the graph and then adds or removes objects as necessary.

Mike Bostock has a great 3 part series explaining this which you can find here: https://twitter.com/mbostock/status/252496768267333632